# Double lexicographic sorting of binary (0-1) matrices

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, graph-algorithm, lexicographic

I want to sort a binary matrix so that its columns and rows are both in lexicographical order by switching rows and columns. In other words, I need a double-lexical ordering of a matrix consisting of zeros and ones, while the entries of all rows and columns remain in their respective row/column. This effectively fills the bottom right side of the resulting matrix with as many `1`s as possible without breaking the columns/rows. (In my case I need the top left side filled, so I simply flipped the result.)

Can someone provide me with a link to code doing that? A very appreciated bonus would be if the algorithm works with tensors of any dimension.

I first tried to sort all rows lexicographically and then all columns, repeating this until the obtained matrix did not change anymore. I compared this with first sorting the columns and used the better result. However with this the result seemed to get stuck in some sort of local optimum and did not produce the best possible result. So I looked for existing algorithms but did not find anything implemented and quickly usable.

I found an old [paper on sciencedirect.com](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002001909390209R)
[1] 
 that does exactly that in ***O(mn)*** but have trouble implementing it. Maybe someone with access can help me with the code and especially with

- the `pointers` which are meant to keep track of the column blocks that were not yet split in a call to `dlrefine`.
- And with the `bucket` filling where it can fail some times.

[1]: *Spinrad, Jeremy P. "Doubly lexical ordering of dense 0–1 matrices." Information Processing Letters 45.5 (1993): 229-235.*

Here is the erroneous Matlab code from my implementation attempt:

```matlab
function [A,I]=dlpartition(M)
    Rout={};
    RP={1:size(M,1)};
    Rlast=1;
    CP={1:size(M,2)};
    pointers=ones(1,size(M,1));
    while Rlast>0
        R=RP{Rlast};
        C=[];
        if any(pointers(R)>0)
            Clast=pointers(R);
            Clast=min(Clast(Clast>0));
            C=CP{Clast}; %the last column block unexamined by R
        end
        if isempty(C)
            Rlast=Rlast-1;
            Rout=[R Rout];
        else
            [R,C,pointers]=dlrefine(M,R,C,pointers-Clast+1);
            pointers=pointers+Clast-1;
            RP=[RP{1:Rlast-1} R RP{Rlast+1:end}];
            Rlast=Rlast-1+length(R);
            CP=[CP{1:Clast-1} C CP{Clast+1:end}];
        end
    end

    %prepare output to match my needs
    I=reshape(1:numel(M),size(M));
    I=I(flip([Rout{:}]),:);
    I=I(:,flip([CP{:}]));
    A=M(I);
end

function [R,C, pointers]=dlrefine(M,R,C,pointers)
%REFINE Spinrad 1992
%M        Binary matrix to sort
%R        Array of rows in current block
%C        Array of columns in current block
%pointers Array of pointers from all rows to the
%         column block that wasn't split yet by it
%         with offset, such that 1 is the current
%         block C
    C={C};
    for r=R
        c=length(C);
        C2=[];
        if pointers(r) >= c %if Cc has not been split by r
            while isempty(C2) && c > 0
                C1=intersect(C{c},find(M(r,:)));
                C2=setdiff(C{c},C1);
                if ~isempty(C1) && ~isempty(C2)
                    C={C{1:c-1} C2 C1 C{c+1:end}};
                    pointers=pointers+(pointers>=c);
                    %pointers(r)=c-1; %TESTING (normally uncommented)
                end
                %if isempty(C2) %TESTING (normally uncommented)
                    c=c-1;
                %end %TESTING (normally uncommented)
            end
            pointers(r)=c; %TESTING (normally commented out)
        end
    end
    bucket=cell(1,length(C));
    failed=[];
    for r=R
        success=false;
        for sub=length(C):-1:1
            if any(ismember(C{sub},find(1-M(r,:))))
                bucket{sub}=[bucket{sub} r];
                success=true;
                break;
            end
        end
        if ~success
            failed=[failed r];
        end
    end
    R=bucket(end:-1:1);
    R=[R(~cellfun('isempty',R)) failed];
end
```

For convenience, you can run the `dlpartition` function with the same matrix as used in the paper:

```matlab
M=[0 1 0 1 1 0;
   1 0 1 1 1 0;
   0 1 1 1 1 0;
   1 1 0 0 0 1;
   0 1 0 1 0 1;
   1 0 0 1 1 1];
[A I]=dlpartition(M)
```

### Edit:

The code works for the small example given in the paper and produces:

```
A =  1 1 1 1 0 0
     1 1 1 0 0 0
     1 1 0 1 1 0
     1 1 0 0 1 1
     1 0 1 0 0 1
     0 0 1 0 1 1
```

But it fails to generate the global optimum for arbitrary matrices. For example:

```
M=[1 0 1 0 0
   1 1 0 0 1
   1 0 0 0 1
   0 0 1 1 1
   0 0 1 0 1];
[A I]=dlpartition(M)
%this gives            but should give
%A = 1 1 0 0 0         1 1 1 0 0
%    1 0 1 1 0         1 1 0 0 0
%    1 0 1 0 0         1 0 0 1 0
%    0 1 1 0 1         0 1 0 1 1
%    0 1 1 0 0         0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but could you answer some questions:
1) How do we know a doubly lexicographic ordering exists?
2) Is this specific to 0-1 matrices?
3) Do you have a link to the paper that doesn't require requesting access?

Comment: @exfret I appreciate the revival of this unanswered question.

1) Any ordering can be ranked by ` 2^(i+j) M(i, j)` and we are interested in the minimum ranked. (compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944063/getting-a-matrix-lexicographically-sorted-along-both-directions ).
2) This is not specific to 0-1 matrices, but the problem becomes more complex for the general case. My use case also only needed the 0-1 matrices. 3) Sadly, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I note on that [mse page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944063/getting-a-matrix-lexicographically-sorted-along-both-directions) mentioned by @dunkelkoon that the ranking reaches a minimum with the iterative sort, but does not distinguish between forms like this

```
0 0 0       0 0 0
0 0 1  and  0 1 1
1 1 0       1 0 0
```

Perhaps the [algorithm](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0216057) by Anna Lubiw referenced in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098794/complexity-of-lexicographically-ordering-a-matrix) would be of interest.